# How to ssr Svelte and pass data from express in node js

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, svelte

I am trying svelte and I might use it for my future website, but there is on thing that has stopped me from suing many js frameworks/compilers. It is server side rendering (one reason is I use server-less so it would be easier then prerendering). Is there a way to use express to server-side-render svelte on every request and also pass data from my node js app too so I don't have to make a bunch of other request? For example the App.svelte might be:

```html
<script>
    export let data
    let count = 0
</script>

<main>
    <button on:click={count++}>Increase Count BY 1</button>
    <h1>{data}<h1>
</main>
```

and main.js:

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
    
    }
});

export default app;
```

I want to get the data value from the server and use it in the svelte code and also sever-side-render it. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to do this in the end?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using SvelteKit which supports all of this out of the box including a express-like runtime using `adapter-node`?

Comment: I'm landing on this thread after encoutering the problem of sveltekit not really having first class support for express middleware, so you're left with developing in a disconnected pieced together environment that looks nothing like your build environment. if there was a solution to that I'd be using sveltekit 100%